# print the data corresponding to page table entry

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, qemu

I am new to systems programming. I wanted to know how to get the data that corresponds to a page table entry (pte).Here is my setup.

I have a page table entry value a601a865 that corresponds to a virtual address bfcdd360 that has content of 6. I needed to get/access the contents using the physical address a601a865.

I am using uint64_t as the data type for pte and virtual address is of type target_ulong. How do I perform it?

This is the code I used  to find the PTE

```
#define EXCPOE_PAGE 14
hwaddr x86_cpu_handle_enc_page_fault(CPUState *cs, vaddr addr, 
int is_write1,int mmu_idx)
{
X86CPU *cpu = X86_CPU(cs);
CPUX86State *env = &cpu->env;
uint64_t ptep, pte;
target_ulong pde_addr, pte_addr;
int error_code = 0;
int is_dirty, prot, page_size, is_write, is_user;
hwaddr paddr;

uint64_t rsvd_mask = PG_HI_RSVD_MASK;
uint32_t page_offset;
target_ulong vaddr;


is_user = mmu_idx == MMU_USER_IDX;

printf("\n Getting inside the x86_cpu_handle_enc_page_fault -- virtual address %x \n", addr);    

#if defined(DEBUG_MMU)
printf("MMU fault: addr=%" VADDR_PRIx " w=%d u=%d eip=" TARGET_FMT_lx "\n",
       addr, is_write1, is_user, env->eip);
#endif
is_write = is_write1 & 1;

if (!(env->cr[0] & CR0_PG_MASK)) {
    pte = addr;
#ifdef TARGET_X86_64
    if (!(env->hflags & HF_LMA_MASK)) {
        /* Without long mode we can only address 32bits in real mode */
        pte = (uint32_t)pte;
    }
#endif
    prot = PAGE_READ | PAGE_WRITE | PAGE_EXEC;
    page_size = 4096;
    goto do_mapping;
}

if (!(env->efer & MSR_EFER_NXE)) {
    rsvd_mask |= PG_NX_MASK;
}

if (env->cr[4] & CR4_PAE_MASK) {
    uint64_t pde, pdpe;
    target_ulong pdpe_addr;

#ifdef TARGET_X86_64

      if (env->hflags & HF_LMA_MASK) {
        uint64_t pml4e_addr, pml4e;
        int32_t sext;

        //printf("Getting inside the env->hflags & HF_LMA_MASK \n");

        /* test virtual address sign extension */
        sext = (int64_t)addr >> 47;
        if (sext != 0 && sext != -1) {
            env->error_code = 0;
            cs->exception_index = EXCP0D_GPF;
            return 1;
        }

        pml4e_addr = ((env->cr[3] & ~0xfff) + (((addr >> 39) & 0x1ff) << 3)) &
            env->a20_mask;
        pml4e = ldq_phys(cs->as, pml4e_addr);

        //printf("env->hflags & HF_LMA_MASK -- pml4e_addr %x \n",pml4e_addr);
        //printf("env->hflags & HF_LMA_MASK -- pml4e %x \n",pml4e);

        if (!(pml4e & PG_PRESENT_MASK)) {
            goto do_fault;
        }
        if (pml4e & (rsvd_mask | PG_PSE_MASK)) {
            goto do_fault_rsvd;
        }
        if (!(pml4e & PG_ACCESSED_MASK)) {
            pml4e |= PG_ACCESSED_MASK;
            stl_phys_notdirty(cs->as, pml4e_addr, pml4e);
        }
        ptep = pml4e ^ PG_NX_MASK;
        pdpe_addr = ((pml4e & PG_ADDRESS_MASK) + (((addr >> 30) & 0x1ff) << 3)) &
            env->a20_mask;
        pdpe = ldq_phys(cs->as, pdpe_addr);

       // printf("env->hflags & HF_LMA_MASK-- pdpe_addr %x \n",pde_addr);
       // printf("env->hflags & HF_LMA_MASK -- pdpe %x \n",pde);

        if (!(pdpe & PG_PRESENT_MASK)) {
            goto do_fault;
        }
        if (pdpe & rsvd_mask) {
            goto do_fault_rsvd;
        }
        ptep &= pdpe ^ PG_NX_MASK;
        if (!(pdpe & PG_ACCESSED_MASK)) {
            pdpe |= PG_ACCESSED_MASK;
            stl_phys_notdirty(cs->as, pdpe_addr, pdpe);
        }
        if (pdpe & PG_PSE_MASK) {
            /* 1 GB page */
            page_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
            pte_addr = pdpe_addr;
            pte = pdpe;
            goto do_check_protect;
        }
    } else
    #endif
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Getting inside the 64-bit paging \n");
        /* XXX: load them when cr3 is loaded ? */
        pdpe_addr = ((env->cr[3] & ~0x1f) + ((addr >> 27) & 0x18)) &
            env->a20_mask;
        pdpe = ldq_phys(cs->as, pdpe_addr);

        printf("64-bit paging -- cr3 loaded -- pdpe_addr %x \n",pdpe_addr);
        printf("64-bit paging -- cr3 loaded -- cs->as %x \n",cs->as);
        printf("64-bit paging -- cr3 loaded -- pdpe %x \n",pde);

        if (!(pdpe & PG_PRESENT_MASK)) {
            goto do_fault;
        }
        rsvd_mask |= PG_HI_USER_MASK;
        if (pdpe & (rsvd_mask | PG_NX_MASK)) {
            goto do_fault_rsvd;
        }
        ptep = PG_NX_MASK | PG_USER_MASK | PG_RW_MASK;
    }

    pde_addr = ((pdpe & PG_ADDRESS_MASK) + (((addr >> 21) & 0x1ff) << 3)) &
        env->a20_mask;
    pde = ldq_phys(cs->as, pde_addr);

        printf("\n");
        printf("64-bit paging -- pde_addr %x \n",pde_addr);
        printf("64-bit paging -- cs->as %x \n",cs->as);
        printf("64-bit paging -- pde %x \n",pde);

    if (!(pde & PG_PRESENT_MASK)) {
        goto do_fault;
    }
    if (pde & rsvd_mask) {
        goto do_fault_rsvd;
    }
    ptep &= pde ^ PG_NX_MASK;
    if (pde & PG_PSE_MASK) {
        /* 2 MB page */
        page_size = 2048 * 1024;
        pte_addr = pde_addr;
        pte = pde;
        goto do_check_protect;
    }
    /* 4 KB page */
    if (!(pde & PG_ACCESSED_MASK)) {
        pde |= PG_ACCESSED_MASK;
        stl_phys_notdirty(cs->as, pde_addr, pde);
    }
    pte_addr = ((pde & PG_ADDRESS_MASK) + (((addr >> 12) & 0x1ff) << 3)) &
        env->a20_mask;
    pte = ldq_phys(cs->as, pte_addr);

    printf("\n");
    printf("64-bit paging -- pte_addr %x \n",pte_addr);
    printf("64-bit paging -- cs->as %x \n",cs->as);
    printf("64-bit paging -- pte %x \n",pte);

    if (!(pte & PG_PRESENT_MASK)) {
        goto do_fault;
        //pte |= PG_ENC_MASK;  /* Mark the entries with PG_ENC_MASK */
        //printf("Marked the addresses corresponding to Enclave with PG_ENC_MASK successfuly \n");
    }
    // else {
    //printf("\n");    
    //printf("About to map the PTE %x with enclave page mask \n",pte);    
    //pte |= PG_ENC_MASK;  /* Map the entries with PG_ENC_MASK */
    //printf("After Mapping it with PG_ENC_MASK %x \n",pte);
    //printf("Mapped the PTE that points to 4K physical page corresponding to Enclave virtual address %x with PG_ENC_MASK successfuly \n",addr);

    //}
    if (pte & rsvd_mask) {
        goto do_fault_rsvd;
    }
    /* combine pde and pte nx, user and rw protections */
    ptep &= pte ^ PG_NX_MASK;
    page_size = 4096;

} else {

    uint32_t pde;
    printf("\n Getting inside the 32-bit paging, virtual address %x \n", addr);
    printf("Value inside the cr3 register is %"PRIx32" \n", env->cr[3]);

    /* page directory entry */
    pde_addr = ((env->cr[3] & ~0xfff) + ((addr >> 20) & 0xffc)) &
        env->a20_mask;
    pde = ldl_phys(cs->as, pde_addr);

    printf("32-bit paging -- pde_addr %x \n",pde_addr);
    printf("cs->as %x\n",cs->as);
    printf("32-bit paging -- pde %x \n",pde);


    if (!(pde & PG_PRESENT_MASK)) {
        goto do_fault;
    }
    ptep = pde | PG_NX_MASK;

    /* if PSE bit is set, then we use a 4MB page */
    if ((pde & PG_PSE_MASK) && (env->cr[4] & CR4_PSE_MASK)) {
        page_size = 4096 * 1024;
        pte_addr = pde_addr;

        /* Bits 20-13 provide bits 39-32 of the address, bit 21 is reserved.
         * Leave bits 20-13 in place for setting accessed/dirty bits below.
         */
        pte = pde | ((pde & 0x1fe000) << (32 - 13));
        rsvd_mask = 0x200000;
        goto do_check_protect_pse36;
    }

    if (!(pde & PG_ACCESSED_MASK)) {
        pde |= PG_ACCESSED_MASK;
        stl_phys_notdirty(cs->as, pde_addr, pde);
    }

    /* page directory entry */
    pte_addr = ((pde & ~0xfff) + ((addr >> 10) & 0xffc)) &
        env->a20_mask;
    pte = ldl_phys(cs->as, pte_addr);

    printf("32-bit paging -- pte_addr %x\n",pte_addr);
    printf("32-bit paging -- pte %x\n",pte);


    if (!(pte & PG_PRESENT_MASK)) {
        goto do_fault;
    //pte |= PG_ENC_MASK;                 /* Mark the entries with PG_ENC_MASK */
    //printf("Mapped the addresses corresponding to Enclave with PG_ENC_MASK successfuly \n");    

    }


    /* combine pde and pte user and rw protections */
    ptep &= pte | PG_NX_MASK;

    page_size = 4096;
    rsvd_mask = 0;
}

do_check_protect:
rsvd_mask |= (page_size - 1) & PG_ADDRESS_MASK & ~PG_PSE_PAT_MASK;

do_check_protect_pse36:
if (pte & rsvd_mask) {
    goto do_fault_rsvd;
}
ptep ^= PG_NX_MASK;
if ((ptep & PG_NX_MASK) && is_write1 == 2) {
    goto do_fault_protect;
}

switch (mmu_idx) {
case MMU_USER_IDX:
    if (!(ptep & PG_USER_MASK)) {
        goto do_fault_protect;
    }
    if (is_write && !(ptep & PG_RW_MASK)) {
        goto do_fault_protect;
    }
    break;

case MMU_KSMAP_IDX:
    if (is_write1 != 2 && (ptep & PG_USER_MASK)) {
        goto do_fault_protect;
    }
    /* fall through */
case MMU_KNOSMAP_IDX:
    if (is_write1 == 2 && (env->cr[4] & CR4_SMEP_MASK) &&
        (ptep & PG_USER_MASK)) {
        goto do_fault_protect;
    }
    if ((env->cr[0] & CR0_WP_MASK) &&
        is_write && !(ptep & PG_RW_MASK)) {
        goto do_fault_protect;
    }
    break;

default: /* cannot happen */
    break;
}
is_dirty = is_write && !(pte & PG_DIRTY_MASK);
if (!(pte & PG_ACCESSED_MASK) || is_dirty) {
    pte |= PG_ACCESSED_MASK;
    if (is_dirty) {
        pte |= PG_DIRTY_MASK;
    }
    stl_phys_notdirty(cs->as, pte_addr, pte);
}

/* the page can be put in the TLB */
prot = PAGE_READ;
if (!(ptep & PG_NX_MASK) &&
    (mmu_idx == MMU_USER_IDX ||
     !((env->cr[4] & CR4_SMEP_MASK) && (ptep & PG_USER_MASK)))) {
    prot |= PAGE_EXEC;
}
if (pte & PG_DIRTY_MASK) {
    /* only set write access if already dirty... otherwise wait
       for dirty access */
    if (is_user) {
        if (ptep & PG_RW_MASK)
            prot |= PAGE_WRITE;
    } else {
        if (!(env->cr[0] & CR0_WP_MASK) ||
            (ptep & PG_RW_MASK))
            prot |= PAGE_WRITE;
    }
}
do_mapping:
printf("\n");
printf("Inside do_mapping pte is %x\n",pte);
pte = pte & env->a20_mask;

pte |= PG_ENC_MASK; 
printf("PTE after enclave_page_mask %x \n",pte);

/* align to page_size */
pte &= PG_ADDRESS_MASK & ~(page_size - 1);
printf("Inside do_mapping pte after alignment is %x\n",pte);

/* Even if 4MB pages, we map only one 4KB page in the cache to
   avoid filling it too fast */
vaddr = addr & TARGET_PAGE_MASK;
page_offset = vaddr & (page_size - 1);
paddr = pte + page_offset;

printf("Physical address is %x\n",paddr);
//printf("Contents at physical address is %x\n",*;

tlb_set_page(cs, vaddr, paddr, prot, mmu_idx, page_size);
return 0;
do_fault_rsvd:
error_code |= PG_ERROR_RSVD_MASK;
do_fault_protect:
error_code |= PG_ERROR_P_MASK;
do_fault:
error_code |= (is_write << PG_ERROR_W_BIT);
if (is_user)
    error_code |= PG_ERROR_U_MASK;
if (is_write1 == 2 &&
    (((env->efer & MSR_EFER_NXE) &&
      (env->cr[4] & CR4_PAE_MASK)) ||
     (env->cr[4] & CR4_SMEP_MASK)))
    error_code |= PG_ERROR_I_D_MASK;
if (env->intercept_exceptions & (1 << EXCP0E_PAGE)) {
    /* cr2 is not modified in case of exceptions */
    stq_phys(cs->as,
             env->vm_vmcb + offsetof(struct vmcb, control.exit_info_2),
             addr);
} else {
    env->cr[2] = addr;
}
env->error_code = error_code;
cs->exception_index = EXCP0E_PAGE;
return 1;
}
```

Comment: do you know which (if any) `task_struct` owns that pte?

Comment: How do I get info for that?

Comment: How did you get a pte?

Comment: I added the code for your referal. I wanted to access the contents present in paddr when I call do_mapping. Kindly help me out.

Comment: I tried the following : I defined a pointer to the paddr as `int *ptr_paddr;` then made it point to paddr by the following `ptr_paddr = (int *) paddr;` When I try to `printf("Contents of paddr is %d \n", *ptr_addr");`,It seg faults. Although I verified the physical address "paddr" and the "pointer_paddr" are having the same physical address value a601a865. Any idea as to what is wrong in my understanding?

Comment: @SRKV did you find answer? if yes plz reply to your question